# show d3.js graph from rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I have a very basic rails database called mystore.

I would like to graph the output in d3.js but really am just learning javascript and so probably need some basic advice.
The steps I am currently taking to create a graph (but it doesn't work as in no output at all) are:

So far I have tried to follow the tutorial as written [here](http://www.overfitted.com/blog/?p=302) but it requires some translation for my situation and I think there are some mislabelled folders which isn't great. As a result, although I get no errors, I also get no actual output on the html.

I have managed to do the following

a. Download d3.js into a mystore/vendors/javascripts/d3.js using

```
 wget "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"
```

b. Create a graph controller placed here

```
  app/controllers/graph_controller.rb
```

with the following code

```
class GraphController < ApplicationController
  def index
end

def data
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render :json => [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
   end
 end
 end
```

c. Change my config/routes.rb to read

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :users
get 'graph/index'
get 'graph/data', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
 end
```

d.Add

```
//= require d3
```

to

```
mystore/vendor/javascripts/application.js
```

e. Create index.html.erb in views/graphs/ and put in the file the following:

```
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

 <svg id="graph"></svg>
```

f. Write the code here mystore/app/assets/javascripts/graph.js

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: 'data',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {
           draw(data);
       },
       error: function (result) {
           error();
       }
   });

 function draw(data) {
var color = d3.scale.category20b();
var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]);

var chart = d3.select("#graph")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")";
          });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
               return color(d)
           })

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
              return x(d) - 10;
          })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .text(function (d) {
              return d;
          });
}

function error() {
console.log("error")
}
```

Then I added a precompile instruction to

```
  config/initializers/assets.rb

  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( graph.js )
```

However when I then go to https://railstbb-sebastiz.c9.io/graph/index all I get is a blank page. I know it is including the javascript as when I view source for the html I get

```
<body>
<script src="/assets/graph.self-bf6010f31204bb0c8220a909025fb7ea8069380ecd1042736333020a21e54da8.js?body=1"></script>
<svg id="graph"></svg>

</body>
</html>
```

and when I go to https://railstbb-sebastiz.c9.io/graph/data I get the data just written out in a line

What have I done wrong here? Surely there is some wiring up that I am missing?